# READIOPS metric graph is not showing anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

Hi I am using aws document db to do some performance testing .I am doing only read operations for certain period of time .But strangely I am not seeing anything in READOPS count metric

Answer (score 0):

ReadIOPS metric refers to disk read I/O operations. It's possible that your data set is cached in RAM, hence the database server doesn't need to fetch the documents from the physical storage.
Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/cloud_watch.html), metrics like `DocumentsReturned` or `OpcountersQuery` could be what you are looking for.